# Returning Object from Classic Asp

Tags: asp-classic

I am using Classic Asp to build request to a url which is successful now the problem
is that I want to return the Request object from the function and getting the following 
problem:
Object doesn't support this property or method,
How can I do it ?

```
Set objSrvHTTP = Server.CreateObject ("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")
objSrvHTTP.open "POST","Https://",False,"",""
objSrvHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
objSrvHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & EncodeBase64("sales@nutritionexpress.co.uk:f00tball")
objSrvHTTP.SetRequestHeader "dev-t", " MyAccessKey "
objSrvHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Cookie", "ubid-main=172-9288630-2514702; session-id=026-6553457-3334020; session-id-time=1191279600l;"
objSrvHTTP.send
BuildRequest=objSrvHTTP
```

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Change

```
BuildRequest=objSrvHTTP
```

to

```
Set BuildRequest=objSrvHTTP
```

to return the object.